# SSH connection to the GIT through a jump server with stdin/stdout forwarding

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

SSH connection to the GIT through a jump server with stdin/stdout forwardingI'm trying to establish a connection from client server (A) to the remote server (C) using an intermediate jump server (B), which should hide a private ssh key for that connection.

Server A needs an ssh access to some resource (git) without any password/ppk authentication:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@serverB:portB/some/repository.git -vvv
```

Server B is a containerized application (a docker container) with `EXPOSE portB` and CMD like:

```bash
$ ssh \
    -v \
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -o ForwardAgent=yes \
    -o TCPKeepAlive=yes \
    -o ConnectTimeout=5 \
    -o ServerAliveCountMax=10 \
    -o ServerAliveInterval=15 \
    -i /root/ssh-import/id_rsa \
    -p $SSH_TUNNEL_PORT \
    -L $LOCAL_HOST:$LOCAL_PORT:$REMOTE_HOST:$REMOTE_PORT \
    $SSH_TUNNEL_USER@$SSH_TUNNEL_HOST \
    -N
```

This configuration isn't a proxy for stdin/stdout forwarding, but a port forwarding using an ssh tunnel. Also tried `-W` and `-J` and `-o ProxyCommand`, but it ends with the following error:

```
$ ssh -i ./ed25519_ppk -W serverC:portC -p portB userB@serverB
... (after a connection attempt)
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

How can I organize my CMD and jump server (B) configuration to establish a key-free ssh connection from the server A to C?